# Changing value of UITextField using an array doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsarray

I have an array located within the variable lstaInfo, as follows:

```
[0] = fruits 
[1] = bee 
[2] = computer
[3] = cars
```

And I'm entering every part of the array in its respective text field, as follows:

```
-(void)setFields{

  field0.text = lstaInfo[0];
  field1.text = lstaInfo[1];
  field2.text = lstaInfo[2];
  field3.text = lstaInfo[3];
}
```

I'm calling `setFields` function in `viewDidLoad`, but every time I run the simulator, it crashes and returns me an error message called:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

The array is perfect and IBOutlets also, could someone help me?

Comment: Can you get the complete crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the array:

```
NSArray *lstaInfo = @[@"fruits",@"bee", @"computer", @"car"];
```

Then populating fields:

```
-(void)setFields{

  field0.text = lstaInfo[0];
  field1.text = lstaInfo[1];
  field2.text = lstaInfo[2];
  field3.text = lstaInfo[3];
}
```

Comment: @user3372120 did you initialise the array and populated it as I indicated?

Comment: @user3372120 If this solved your problem would you mind marking this as correct answer for reference of other people please? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the "text" property of the UITextField.

It should be:

field0.text = lstaInfo[0];

Answer (score 1):

Try to call setFields on `viewWillAppear`. The `viewDidLoad` method only is called once, when the view is loaded.

Comment: In this scenario it does not matter, because he is running the app and on first go itself it is crashing.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wrote it just in case. He had to initialize the array like you said.